# Is *++*p acceptable syntax?

Tags: c

In K&R Section 5.10, in their sample implementation of a `grep`-like function, there are these lines:

```
while (--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-')
    while (c = *++argv[0])
```

Understanding the syntax there was one of the most challenging things for me, and even now a couple weeks after viewing it for the first time, I still have to think very slowly through the syntax to make sense of it.  I compiled the program with this alternate syntax, but I'm not sure that the second line is allowable.  I've just never seen `*`'s and `++`'s interleaved like this, but it makes sense to me, it compiles, and it runs.  It also requires no parentheses or brackets, which is maybe part of why it seems more clear to me.  I just read the operators in one direction only (right to left) rather than bouncing back and forth to either side of the variable name.

```
while (--argc > 0 && **++argv == '-')
    while (c = *++*argv)
```

Comment: Looks like undefined behavior to me.

Comment: A little correction. `argv[0]` should be const IMHO. That is, the `argv` is a function argument which is not const, but it points to a read-only array of string pointers. Besides of this - the syntax is ok IMHO for skilled C/C++ programmer

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: What's undefined about it?

Comment: @valdo: The standard specifically says that `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array are modifiable.  Oddly, it doesn't say that the elements of the `argv` array are modifiable (or that they aren't).  I don't know whether that omission is deliberate, but it wasn't changed in C11.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well for one, that's one way to make anyone reading your code to go ***huh?!?!?!***

So, from a readability standpoint, no, you probably shouldn't write code like that.

Nevertheless, it's valid code and breaks down as this:

```
*(++(*p))
```

First, `p` is dereferenced. Then it is incremented. Then it is dereferenced again.

---

To make thing worse, this line:

```
while (c = *++*argv)
```

has an assignment in the loop-condition. So now you have ***two*** side-effects to make your reader's head spin. YAY!!!

Comment: Cool, that's what I thought.  I don't have a lot of experience reading code, so I don't know how common it is or if it would confuse people.  But I don't think it should be confusing, since associativity is right to left for these operators.  Using parentheses as you did may be nice, but it is sort of like saying ((4+5)+7) = 16, is it not?  Not really super important to me one way or the other, nor am I trying to be argumentative... just thinking out loud. :-)

Comment: It's not that confusing if you pause and read it more closely. But it's very uncommon (I've never seen it before), not to mention weird combinations of symbols will look very awkward. (Reminds me of `x --> 0`.)

Comment: @The111: You had to ask the question. That means by definition it is confusing. Code should be readable by everybody from the most experienced to the beginner and be obvious to read (at a glance). I should not need to pick up a book and look up operator precedence to very my assumptions are correct. In my team that code would never get past code review. You would be sent back to re-write it and win the joy of babysitting the servers for the weekend (we have a weekly bad code contest).

Comment: @Loki: My main question was: is it allowable.  Is it confusing was a side question.  But what you say about needing to know precedence rules, I don't think is true.  Keith Thompson pointed out below that even with zero knowledge of precedence rules, there is only one possible way to read the statement.  Also, I don't think anything in C is "obvious to a beginner."  As a newbie myself, I asked about this syntax because it actually makes it more obvious to me, not to try to be difficult or different.

Comment: Although, knowing that it's not "normal" I would definitely stay away from it in an environment where others would read it.  That's probably a ways off for me though.

Comment: @The111: I disagree; the precedence rules are not obvious. If they were nobody would have even mentioned them. Also I mean obvious to read (it may take a while to understand what an algorithm is doing but any individual statement should be obvious to read). Even if you stay away from environments where others have to read it, you still have to read it. Try coming back to the code in 6 months time you will ask the same question again.

Comment: I'm the only one who mentioned precedence. ;-)  And then Keith mentioned it to show me that I was wrong, it wasn't even related.  It's not a matter of precedence (whether it be obvious or not obvious), it's a matter of associativity.  Prefix unary operators can only be read one way.

Answer (score 3):

Seems valid to me. Of course, you should not read it left to right, that's not how C compiler parses the source, and that's not how C language grammatics work. As a rule of thumb, you should first locate the object that's subject to operating upon (in this case - `argv`), and then analyze the operators, often, like in this case, from inside (the object) to outside. The actual parsing (and reading) rules are of course more complicated.

P. S. And personally, I think this line of code is really not hard to understand (and I'm not a C programming guru), so I don't think you should surround it with parentheses as Mysticial suggests. That would only make the code look big, if you know what I mean...

Comment: I only said I read it right to left in this case because I see * and ++ as equal in the precedence table, and both say that they have right to left associativity.  It seems a rare condition where both those things are true at once and you can simply read the operators in this way...

Answer (score 1):

There's no ambiguity, even without knowledge of the precedence rules.

Both `++` and `*` are prefix unary operators; they can only apply to an operand that follows them.  The second `*` can only apply to `argv`, the `++` to `*argv`, and the first `*` to `++*argv`.  So it's equivalent to `*(++(*argv))`.  There's no possible relationship between the precedences of `++` and `*` that could make it mean anything else.

This is unlike something like `*argv++`, which could conceivably be either `(*argv)++` or `*(argv++)`, and you have to apply precedence rules to determine which (it's *(argv++)` because postfix operators bind more tightly than prefix unary operators).

There's a constraint that `++` can only be applied to an lvalue; since `*argv` is an lvalue, that's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks Keith.  What you say in your first few sentences is what I was trying to get at when I said it seems easier for me to mentally process the syntax this way, compared to a situation with operators on both sides of the variable, and you have to "bounce back and forth."  If there are no parentheses required, you can't place them incorrectly, or accidentally omit them!

Answer (score 1):

Is this code valid? Yes, but that's not what you asked.

Is this code acceptable? That depends (acceptable to who?).

I wouldn't consider it acceptable - I'd consider it "harder to read than necessary" for a few different reasons.

First; lots of programmers have to work with several different languages, potentially with different operator precedence rules. If your code looks like it relies on a specific language's operator precedence rules (even if it doesn't) then people have to stop and try to remember which rules apply to which language.

Second; different programmers have different skill levels. If you're ever working in a large team of developers you'll find that the best programmers write code that everyone can understand, and the worst programmers write code that contains subtle bugs that half of the team can't spot. Most C programmers should understand "`*++*argv`", but a good programmer knows that a small number of "not-so-good" programmers either won't understand it or will take a while to figure it out.

Third; out of all the different ways of writing something, you should choose the variation that expresses your intent the best. For this code you're working with an array, and therefore it should look like you intend to be working with an array (and not a pointer). *Note: For the same reason, "`uint32_t foo = 0x00000002;`" is better than "`uint32_t foo = 0x02;`".*